# How to ensure Google Cloud Compute instance is up and running

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I create Google Cloud Compute instance from the shell script, then launch several commands on that instance via ssh.

How to ensure that operating system in the instance is up and running?

For instance:

`gcloud compute instances create "$my_name" \
    --tags "http-server" \
    --image container-vm \
    --metadata-from-file google-container-manifest="container.yml" \
    --zone "$my_zone" \
    --machine-type g1-small`

then I want to run either

`gcloud compute ssh \
      "$my_name" --zone "$my_zone" \
      --command 'sudo docker stop $(sudo docker ps -q -a)'`

or 

`gcloud compute copy-files \
    some.conf root@"$my_name":/existing_dir/ \
    --zone "$my_zone"`

As far as I understand, the second command may fail with connection refuse if the instance is not up.

How to ensure that instance is up and ready to accept ssh connection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just check that SSH port is open before sending the command. SSH server won't be up until the instance OS is up:

```
IP=$(gcloud compute instances list | awk '/'$my_name'/ {print $5}')
if nc -w 1 -z $IP 22; then
    echo "OK! Ready for heavy metal"
    : Do your heavy metal work
else
    echo "Maybe later?"
fi
```

Explanation:

> 1. Get the IP for instance $my_name
> 2. Check if port 22 is accepting incoming connections.
>
> > -w: Connection timeout (1 second should be more that enough)
> >
> > -z: Check only if port is open and exit inmediately

Comment: I seems that VM start can take more than 5 seconds

Comment: Check for the instance to be available inside a loop. Instance boot time depends on the instance boot configuration :)

Comment: This is a good approach.  One caveat is that gcloud's default table format is intended to be convenient and human readable, but not long term stable, so it's possible for new fields to be added in the future and break awk.  Instead I recommend calling
    `gcloud compute instances list instance-name --format json`
to get a more stable output format.  You can parse json output with `jq`.  (Other stable output formats include text and yaml.)

Comment: --format text is more unix filtering friendly, in my opinion, and does not require an external tool as jq. Once you have a basic approach working, the only things left are details.

Comment: You can make it more robust by searching the response for an IPv4 address: `$( gcloud compute instances list --format text |sed -rn 's/.*([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}).*/\1/p' )`

Answer (score 4):

If you have to ensure ssh is available, there is a script for that.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function wait_vm_up {
  local counter=0

  local readonly project=${1:?"project required"}
  local readonly instance=${2:?"instance required"}
  local readonly zone=${3:?"zone required"}
  local readonly user=${4:?"user required"}
  local readonly maxRetry=${5:-100}

  echo "Project: $project"
  echo "Instance: $instance"
  echo "MaxRetry: $maxRetry"

  while true ; do
    if (( $counter == $maxRetry )) ; then
      echo "Reach the retry upper limit $counter"
      exit 1
    fi

    gcloud compute ssh --quiet --zone "$zone" "$user@$instance" --tunnel-through-iap --project "$project" --command="true" 2> /dev/null

    if (( $? == 0 )) ;then
      echo "The machine is UP !!!"
      exit 0
    else
      echo "Maybe later? $counter"
      ((counter++))
      sleep 1
    fi
  done
}

wait_vm_up $@
```

Comment: I've never seen that `${1:?"project required"}` expression before what is that called?  I searched for `${1:?` in https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html but didn't find anything.

Comment: Search for `${parameter:?word}` in [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Answer (score 2):

easy cross-platform solution:

`gcloud compute --verbosity error --project "MYPROJECT" ssh "MYINSTANCE" -- "echo instance now up" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no`

loop that until you get errorLevel=0

Comment: For me if the VM is not running this fails rather hard, with a python stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [startup scripts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) do the work for you :D

or using the [REST APIs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/get) you can polling the instance status

Comment: REST API way needs authorization and looks too complicated from shell perspective.

Comment: I guess `container-vm` image already has startup script defined. Would startup script work with `container-vm` image?

Comment: If you use python call a gapi from shell it's simply: create a python script that do the job and use it from sh. About pre-defined image scripts I think it's works: try it and let me know!

Comment: why do you guis downvoted the best answer? API is the proper way to comunicate with google. Everything else is mere trash that changes every day ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command: gcloud compute instances describe 'instance name' --zone 'zone name' | grep "status: RUNNING"

If you get the exact output **status: RUNNING** it'll indicate the instance is up and running.

Comment: It doesn't work. As per the documentation:
RUNNING - The instance is booting up or running. You can connect to the instance shortly after it enters this state.

Answer (score -1):

Simple command line or alias.

```
alias gcp_status_MY_MACHINE='gcloud compute instances describe salesforce --zone "ZONE" --project "PROJECT" | grep status'
```

If you only have one project and don't specify the zone it will still work, this is just the verbose version.